# Moving from HttpClient to HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, http-post, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

I had developed a android app with `HttpClient` with target API 19. In order to do some updates I updated target API 22. As soon as I did, I noticed that a ton of previous implementations are now deprecated. So, I tried to move to newer and better `HttpUrlConnection` but I am facing some hard time doing this.

I have already been through various threads on SO but I do not have much knowledge regarding such connections.

Here is the code I am been using for API 19 -

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://example.com/exchweb/bin/auth/owaauth.dll");

try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username.getText().toString().trim()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("destination", "https://example.com/exchange/" + username.getText().toString().trim()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("flags",
                                "0"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rdoPublic", "0"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rdoTrusted", "4"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post,httpContext);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {            
        // Saving line for use
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
    }

} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It maybe answered somewhere but there are so many examples to look at and I being a novice finds very hard to get a working one.

and a question - Does HttpUrlConnection saves session itself as HttpContext do? If no then please help me know that too, much appreciated.

Thanks for listening! Please comment if you need anything more.

Cheers

Comment: checkout following link, you will find your answer hopefully: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: I would recommend you to skip period of inventing wheels and to start using `Retrofit`.

Comment: @Fox can you briefly explain your point?

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ - library which helps to make http requests without creating connections, contexts, readers and other stuff.

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` is not 'newer'. It is about fifteen years *older*. Your purpose and question remain obscure.

Comment: Here you find [a list of libraries](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background) you can use to make life easier. HttpURLConnection is recommended by Google, but I'm sure they don't use it "natively", they probably use Volley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [**Basic HTTP Client**](https://github.com/turbomanage/basic-http-client) library. It's usage is same as **HttpClient** but deep in sources is created using **HttpUrlConnection** which is not depreceated.